# Print Image object using java

Tags: java, image, printing

I retrieved an image from the database as an array of bytes,then I display this image in image icon ,but I faced problem which is I want to connect my java program to the printer and send printing requests by the code  ..and I don't know how ..could someone help me please?
here is the code..

```
byte[]img=rs.getBytes("BarCode");
ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(img);
Image image=icon.getImage();
```

Comment: What have you already researched?

Comment: I am not sure..but I saw some codes and they use printJob ..but they deals with files and they put the path of image and I don’t want to do it in this way ..I want to print the same image that I retrived..@PM77-1

Comment: When you have an `ImageIcon`, you can create a `JLabel label = new JLabel(imageIcon);`, and then should be able to print this label with `label.print(g)`, as described in the docs at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/printable.html (TBH: I never tried it, but if you encounter a problem with that, you should provide more of your current code and say more specifically what the actual problem is)

Comment: @Marco13 thanks a lot I will try it 

Comment: It works  but inestad of JLabel I print it in JPanel @Marco13

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6731871/carrot-show thanks